# What RSS/Atom standard to use for feed generation?

Tags: xml, rss

Reading online about this topic is confusing. Is there a way to cut around the history, politics and technicalities to answer the question: Which standard should I refer to when I write code to generate feeds?

I want to use UTF-8 encoding, which may affect the choice. Otherwise I'm most interested in compatibility with a decent range of readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you *really* feel like wasting a week or two debugging weird reader bugs, use Atom. Specifically, the IETF-standardized Atom 1.0, also known as RFC 4287. A few years ago it wasn't widely supported, but every reader released in the last 5 years or so can handle it fine.

The RFC is quite long, but most of it is optional features (encryption, extensions, obscure elements) which don't matter if you're writing a generator.

Remember to use [feedvalidator.org](http://feedvalidator.org/) to check your output.

Comment: Thanks for the validator link. How do you feel about the W3 RSS Validator http://validator.w3.org/feed/?

Comment: They use the same engine and generate the same results, but the W3C's URL is more difficult to remember

Answer (score 0):

As a data collector and crawler author, I prefer Atom 1.0 for crawling.

RSS 2.0 or Atom 1.0

I've never actually published a feed, though.

Answer (score 0):

Get the best of both worlds, XML has namespaces, nowadays it's pretty common to use RSS with a view elements from the Atom namespace in it.

Comment: Is RFC 4287 (as John Millikin mentioned) the standard for what you're referring to?

Answer (score -1):

Look at a feed produced by the NY Times and do exactly what they do. Every app has to work with their feeds.